# Как приостановить все потоки(таски) кроме одного до его завершения?

Tags: c#, task

Допустим, мне надо динамически создавать таски для обработки какой-либо информации:

```
var listFiles = Directory.GetFiles(pathDir, "*.txt");
var listTasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var file in listFiles)
{
    var tempTask = new Task(() => ReadFile(file, pattern, strongMatch));
    listTasks.Add(tempTask);
    listTasks[listTasks.Count-1].Start();
}
```

Эти таски внутри себя что-то параллельно считают, а потом выводят построчно результаты своей работы, вызывая функцию Out():

```
Task task = new Task(() => Out(pathFile, strings));
task.Start();
```

Мне надо во время вызова функции Out() приостановить выполнение всех остальных тасков, чтобы не происходило смешения выдачи результатов в консоли, как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Эксклюзивный доступ к разделяемому ресурсу проще всего организовать при помощи `lock`. Или если у вас разделяемым ресурсом является один метод, то подойдёт `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`.

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
void Out(string pathFile, IEnumerable<string> strings)
{
    ...
}
```

Если ресурс более сложен, чем просто вызов метода, то поможет `lock`:

```
static private readonly object mutex = new object();
```

```
lock (mutex)
{
    Out(pathFile, strings1);
    Out(pathFile, strings2);
}
```

Ну и если операция `Out` реально длинная, и ваши функции асинхронные, то для повышения эффективности можно воспользоваться более медленным, но зато асинхронным `AsyncLock` [отсюда](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/02/12/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-6-asynclock/) или [отсюда](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/wiki/AsyncLock):

```
private static readonly AsyncLock mutex = new AsyncLock();
```

```
using (await mutex.LockAsync())
{
    Out(pathfile, strings);
}
```

При этом, возможно, Out стоит тоже сделать асинхронным, или вызывать через

```
await Task.Run(() => Out(pathfile, strings));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.

Comment: @KorwinD: Пожалуйста!